# Contosouniversity database can`t transmit data from model to web or db

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I do code as in asp.net code first. Models, Views and Controllers. https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-applicationBut when I run app in google chrome or another browser there is no db elements from DAL in html displays.
I can create data via google chrome and save it. And retrieve it from the next run, But I do not know where it stores data that I can add throufg C# and Entity dbset like.

```
new Student
{
    FirstMidName="Carson",
    LastName="Alexander",
    EnrollmentDate=DateTime.Parse("2005-09-01")
}
```

OK. it runs but no student in application added through this code.
Connection exists in Server Explorer with all tables referencing 
student class 
But no data through html. And when I run SQL server separately I can`t even find DB with corresponding name.

Comment: The `<connectionStrings>` section in your `web.config` should tell you the location and default db.

Comment: Search for LocalDB database

Comment: I try some thinds. I change server name to my server and I can see DB in SQL Server. But I SchoolInitializer from DAL can`t create nothing.